# How to Execute a ScriptBlock with SessionState correctly inside a ICommandPredictor?

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-module, powershell-7.2

Hi I'm trying to execute a `ScriptBlock` with a specific `SessionState` inside a `ICommandPredictor`, but if the `ScriptBlock` has a pipe in it just hangs forever (Could be a deadlock).

I have a project that recreates the issue [here](https://github.com/AnderssonPeter/PowerShellScriptBlockHang).

To recreate the issue:

1. Clone the repo
2. Open in Visual Studio 2021
3. Set a breakpoint in `Predictor.cs` on [line 23](https://github.com/AnderssonPeter/PowerShellScriptBlockHang/blob/1c5476681695216c14fdf12dd528084ac422aae7/PowerShellScriptBlockHang/Predictor.cs#L23)
4. Start with debugging
5. Type one char into the terminal that opens up.
6. Visual studio should popup with the breakpoint hit
7. Press F10 (Step over)
8. You will never reach [line 28](https://github.com/AnderssonPeter/PowerShellScriptBlockHang/blob/1c5476681695216c14fdf12dd528084ac422aae7/PowerShellScriptBlockHang/Predictor.cs#L28) or [31](https://github.com/AnderssonPeter/PowerShellScriptBlockHang/blob/1c5476681695216c14fdf12dd528084ac422aae7/PowerShellScriptBlockHang/Predictor.cs#L31) as we are stuck.

So I might have done something wrong in how I execute ScriptBlocks..
But the flow is:

1. When the Terminal starts it executes [Install-ScriptBlock](https://github.com/AnderssonPeter/PowerShellScriptBlockHang/blob/main/PowerShellScriptBlockHang/InstallScriptBlock.cs)

   1. This exectues a `ScriptBlock` with a new Session that in turn executes [set-scriptblock](https://github.com/AnderssonPeter/PowerShellScriptBlockHang/blob/main/PowerShellScriptBlockHang/SetScriptBlock.cs), `set-scriptblock` stores the provided `ScriptBlock` and the new `SessionState`.
   2. Create a ICommandPredictor and register it with the Subsystem.
2. When you type in the terminal the `ICommandPredictor` is invoked, this in turn tries to execute the scriptblock that was saved with `set-scriptblock` using the same session.

I hope this makes sense and I know the flow is somewhat convoluted, but I can't remove any of the steps in the flow without breaking my use case..

So is there any way I could change this to allow me to execute a `ScriptBlock` inside a `ICommandPredictor` with a `SessionState` that was created when executing a `ScriptBlock` without causing it to hang?

In case my link ever breaks it has the following code:

```cs
[Cmdlet("Install", "ScriptBlock"), OutputType(typeof(bool))]
public class InstallScriptBlock : PSCmdlet
{


    public static string AssemblyPath
    {
        get
        {
            string codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
            return Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path); ;
        }
    }

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(AssemblyPath), "script.ps1");
        var script = ScriptBlock.Create("set-scriptblock -Expression { @( 'One', ' *$Two' ) | % { $_.trim(\" *$\") } }");
        InvokeCommand.InvokeScript(true, script, new List<object>());
        InvokeCommand.InvokeScript("Set-PSReadLineOption -PredictionSource Plugin");
        SubsystemManager.RegisterSubsystem<ICommandPredictor, Predictor>(new Predictor());
        base.ProcessRecord();
    }

}

public class Predictor : ICommandPredictor
{
    public string Description => "TestHang";

    public Guid Id => new Guid("7959E3B3-8444-478A-A821-48A07FB407DF");

    public string Name => "TestHang";

    public bool CanAcceptFeedback(PredictionClient client, PredictorFeedbackKind feedback)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public SuggestionPackage GetSuggestion(PredictionClient client, PredictionContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            //The line below will cause a permanent hang of this thread!
            var result = State.InvokeCommand.InvokeScript(State.SessionState, State.ScriptBlock);
            //We never get here!
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }        

        return default;
    }

    public void OnCommandLineAccepted(PredictionClient client, IReadOnlyList<string> history)
    {
    }

    public void OnCommandLineExecuted(PredictionClient client, string commandLine, bool success)
    {
    }

    public void OnSuggestionAccepted(PredictionClient client, uint session, string acceptedSuggestion)
    {
    }

    public void OnSuggestionDisplayed(PredictionClient client, uint session, int countOrIndex)
    {
    }
}

[Cmdlet("Set", "ScriptBlock"), OutputType(typeof(bool))]
public class SetScriptBlock : PSCmdlet
{
    /// <summary>
    /// <para type="description">Indicates whether the user would like to receive output. </para>
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter(Mandatory = true)]
    public ScriptBlock Expression { get; set; } = null!;


    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        State.ScriptBlock = Expression;
        State.SessionState = SessionState;
        State.InvokeCommand = InvokeCommand;
        base.ProcessRecord();
    }
}

static class State
{
    public static CommandInvocationIntrinsics InvokeCommand { get; set; }
    public static SessionState SessionState { get; set; }
    public static ScriptBlock ScriptBlock { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Where do you define the scriptblock that "has a pipe in it"?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen https://github.com/AnderssonPeter/PowerShellScriptBlockHang/blob/1c5476681695216c14fdf12dd528084ac422aae7/PowerShellScriptBlockHang/InstallScriptBlock.cs#L26

Comment: The fact that is doesn't fail until the predictor runs indicates you should be able to run the scriptblock with `InvokeCommand.InvokeScript(true, script, new List<object>())` (like you do in `Install-ScriptBlock`) instead of the alternative overload you're currently using in the predictor

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen correct me if I'm wrong but then it does not use the same state any more? Not that the code above is the most simplified version that I have, the one I need to use in production is much more complicated and has references to local variables (I guess those are stored in the SessionState?)